# clock gating verilog code not working correctly

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, clock, hdl

I'm to trying to code a clock gating logic  that allows data to pass only at the posedge write_clk_en. the code is compiled correctly in EDA playground but the output is not as intended.So according to code,

```
@ (posedge write_clk_en)begin
 data_in[3] <= 1'b1;
end
```

at this instance the write_clk_en is disabled, so data_in[3] NBA should be halted and it waits for next valid posedge (which is the next posedge of write_clk_en here), data_in[3] should be written. But that is not happening, rather the gated clock period is also getting considered and the NBA assignment is occurring even when write_clk_en is gated for 4th pulse.What could be the issue ?.the wave form is shown here.

[image]

the sv code :

```
module tb;

logic [4:0]  data_in;
logic  write_clk;
logic  write_clk_en;
logic write_clk_mod;  
logic [5:0] write_clk_init;

always//write_clk 500M
  begin
        write_clk  =0;
    #10 write_clk = 1;
    #10 write_clk = 0;
  end


initial begin
  $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
  $dumpvars;
  #10000 $finish;
end  

initial begin
data_in=5'b00000;
write_clk_init = 6'b000000;
write_clk_mod=0;
end

initial begin
write_clk_init =6'b110111;
end

initial begin
repeat (3) begin
@(posedge write_clk)begin
if(write_clk_init[0]==1 || write_clk_init[0]==0)
write_clk_mod<=write_clk_init[0];
end
@(posedge write_clk)begin
if(write_clk_init[1]==1 || write_clk_init[1]==0)
write_clk_mod<=write_clk_init[1];
end
@(posedge write_clk)begin
if(write_clk_init[2]==1 || write_clk_init[2]==0)
write_clk_mod<=write_clk_init[2];
end
@(posedge write_clk)begin
if(write_clk_init[3]==1 || write_clk_init[3]==0)
write_clk_mod<=write_clk_init[3];
end
@(posedge write_clk)begin
if(write_clk_init[4]==1 || write_clk_init[4]==0)
write_clk_mod<=write_clk_init[4];
end
@(posedge write_clk)begin
if(write_clk_init[5]==1 || write_clk_init[5]==0)
write_clk_mod<=write_clk_init[5];
end
end
end

  always @ (*) begin 
  write_clk_en  = write_clk & write_clk_mod;
end

initial begin 

@ (posedge write_clk_en)begin
data_in[0] <= 1'b1;
end
@ (posedge write_clk_en)begin
data_in[1] <= 1'b1;
end
@ (posedge write_clk_en)begin
 data_in[2] <= 1'b1;
 end
@ (posedge write_clk_en)begin
 data_in[3] <= 1'b1;
end
@ (posedge write_clk_en)begin
data_in[4] <= 1'b1;
end

end


endmodule
```

Comment: looks like you got a glitch on wire_clk_en. Most likely due to the fact that you overused nbas in generating write_clk_mod. use blocking assignments there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within initial blocks, change your NBAs to BAs. NBAs should only be used within an `always @(posedge clocksignal) block`

Take also into account that in simulations, `@(posedge clocksignal)` blocks (without the reserved word `always`) are treated as delays (wait until a rising edge clk event happens, then continue simulation). By the way you have written these blocks in your initial statements, I didn't know for sure if you were aware of their true behaviour. I've rewritten those `@(posedge)` blocks to make the simulation flow a bit clear.

I have also merged some of your initial blocks into one. Every initial block you have is started at the same time (simulation time 0). Particulary, `write_clk_init` is assigned in two different initial blocks.

This edited code works as expected. It is also available at https://www.edaplayground.com/x/3VYk

[image: OpenWavwe output]

```
module tb;
  reg [4:0]  data_in;
  reg  write_clk;
  reg  write_clk_en;
  reg write_clk_mod;  
  reg [5:0] write_clk_init;

  initial begin
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
    $dumpvars;
    #10000 $finish;
  end  

  initial begin
    data_in = 5'b00000;
    write_clk_init = 6'b110111;
    write_clk_mod = 0;
    write_clk = 0;

    repeat (3) begin
      @(posedge write_clk);
      if(write_clk_init[0]==1 || write_clk_init[0]==0)
          write_clk_mod = write_clk_init[0];

      @(posedge write_clk);
      if(write_clk_init[1]==1 || write_clk_init[1]==0)
          write_clk_mod = write_clk_init[1];

      @(posedge write_clk);
      if(write_clk_init[2]==1 || write_clk_init[2]==0)
          write_clk_mod = write_clk_init[2];

      @(posedge write_clk);
      if(write_clk_init[3]==1 || write_clk_init[3]==0)
          write_clk_mod = write_clk_init[3];

      @(posedge write_clk);
      if(write_clk_init[4]==1 || write_clk_init[4]==0)
          write_clk_mod = write_clk_init[4];

      @(posedge write_clk);
      if(write_clk_init[5]==1 || write_clk_init[5]==0)
          write_clk_mod = write_clk_init[5];
    end
  end

  always @* begin 
    write_clk_en  = write_clk & write_clk_mod;
  end

  initial begin 
    @(posedge write_clk_en);
    data_in[0] = 1'b1;

    @(posedge write_clk_en);
    data_in[1] = 1'b1;

    @(posedge write_clk_en);
    data_in[2] = 1'b1;

    @(posedge write_clk_en);
    data_in[3] = 1'b1;

    @(posedge write_clk_en);
    data_in[4] = 1'b1;
  end

  always begin
    write_clk = #10 ~write_clk;
  end      
endmodule
```